# Laravel bulk insert with column that contains an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a data structure that has the following columns:

```
id => increments()
name => string()
data => string()
```

In my model, I cast the data column to an array.

```
    protected $casts = [
    'data' => 'array'
    ];
```

In a for loop I create a multidimensional array like this called `$data` and I assign it to the 'data key of my `$temp` array and I push it in an array called `$finals`.

```
$temp = [
'name' => $variable1,
'data' => $data
]

array_push($finals, $temp)
```

Unfortunately, Laravel's bulk insert does not allow me to execute a bulk insert when I have a multidimensional array where one of the values is an array. In order to insert this type of multidimensional array I have to create the following `foreach loop` (which I don't like)

```
foreach($finals, $final)
{
    ModalName::create($final);
}
```

Is there a way that I could insert such a data structure in a single statement and not loop through each element of the array. Something like

```
ModelName::create($finals);
```

Note that, I've tried to replace the value of the 'data' key with a hardcoded static value in place of the array and the rows are inserted correctly.

The multidimensional array $finals looks like this.

```
array:2 [
    0 => [
        'name' => 'name_value',
        'data' => [
            "key" => "value",
            "key2" => "value2"
           ]
    ]
   1 => [
        'name' => 'name_value2',
        'data' => [
              'key' => 'value',
              'key2' => 'value2'
            ]
    ]
]
```

**EDIT::**

Please note that when I try to use

```
ModelName::create($finals) or 
ModalName::insert($finals) or 
DB::table('table_name')->insert($finals)
```

I get the following query exception: **Array to string conversion**

Comment: Laravel doesn't provide a way to do that - prepare your `data` as string or use multiple calls using `Eloquent` (attribute casting as defined on the model)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the casted field/data into `json_encode`:

```
$insert = [
    0 => [
        'name' => 'name_value',
        'data' => json_encode([
            "key" => "value",
            "key2" => "value2"
           ])
    ]
   1 => [
        'name' => 'name_value2',
        'data' => json_encode([
              'key' => 'value',
              'key2' => 'value2'
            ])
    ]
]
```

then insert:

```
Model::insert($insert);
```

This will NOT create a JSON STRING but will preserve the structure as long as you have this in the Model:

```
protected $casts = [
   'data' => 'array',
];
```